# Why does grep not extract from security utility's output? Comparable extraction from echo works

Tags: regex, bash, macos, grep, keychain

In OS X, there is a command-line utility called `security` which is designed to access the Keychain. It can return the password of an entry in the Keychain, which is what I'm trying to do. When I run `security find-internet-password -ga an_entry | grep "password"` I get the following output, as expected:

```
password: "apassword123"
```

I would like to extract the text between the quotes. `grep`, specifically `pcregrep`, should work but doesn't:

```
echo 'password: "apassword123"' | pcregrep -o '^password:\s"(?!_)\K[^"]+'
```

Returns:

```
apassword123
```

As expected, but:

```
security find-internet-password -ga anentry | pcregrep -o '^password:\s"(?!_)\K[^"]+'
```

Returns:

```
password: "apassword123"
```

Which is absurd.

Comment: It might be simpler to just use the `-w` option to `security`; I'm generally of the opinion that life is too short to waste time figuring out Perl regexes.

Comment: @chepner while this option works, this question is still pretty interesting

Comment: @ThomasAyoub, ...is it? "stderr doesn't go through pipelines" isn't exactly rocket science, and this question as currently posed isn't likely to come up in search results for someone hitting the same problem with a different tool generating that stream on stderr.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as I was not aware that security output was going through stderr, it was...

Comment: *nod*. Actually, I'll admit to being surprised they do it that way rather than writing straight to the TTY -- which would be at least a bit harder to capture, and thus more secure against abuse (which is presumably the point of not using stdout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output actually doesn't get through the `grep` as it's on stderr. You should be able to do this by redirecting the stderr to stdout like

```
security find-internet-password -ga anentry 2>&1 | pcregrep -o '^password:\s"(?!_)\K[^"]+'
```

Comment: I didn't know that stderr isn't passed through pipes. Thanks.